# How to group bar chart that using value list as dimension?

Tags: dimensions, qliksense

I want  to divide the chart into two parts, the first four need to be in one group called ETY and the rest belong to another group called PPY

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu3VG.png)
My dimension : =ValueList('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM','Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')

My measure : `if( valuelist('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='PE-UCC' , sum(LLDPE)/(200000/12) ,
                                                                    if( valuelist('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='PE-SDK',Sum(HDPE)/(136000/12),
                                                                                                                                   if(ValueList('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='SM', Sum(SMI) / (340000/12),
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    if( ValueList( 'PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='Sales Dist', (Sum(PENI)+Sum(SULFINDO)+Sum(POlychem)+ Sum(ASAHI) +Sum( Mc ) +Sum(Ship))/38000,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      if(ValueList('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='PP1',Sum(PP1)/(Floor(MonthEnd(Max(DATE))) - Floor(MonthStart(Max(DATE))) + 1)/24/20,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           if(ValueList('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='PP2',Sum(PP2)/(Floor(MonthEnd(Max(DATE))) - Floor(MonthStart(Max(DATE))) + 1)/24/20,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              if(ValueList('PE-UCC','PE-SDK','SM', 'Sales Dist','PP1','PP2','PP3')='PP3',Sum(PP3)/(Floor(MonthEnd(Max(DATE))) - Floor(MonthStart(Max(DATE))) + 1)/24/20)))))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group dimension, for it you must create a new dimension with grouped values. In this video, you can view as developed it.

[Dimensions - Grouping](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2017/Content/Videos/Videos-dimensions-grouping.htm)

[Qlik Sense Desktop – Drill-down Group Dimension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55TN-bZ3WWU)

When you have created the dimension, only add it to the bar chart and add your measure.